# Cómo extraer en Scala desde MongoDB un objeto, que está en un array, y éste está dentro de otro objeto?

Tags: mongodb, scala

Estamos intentando recuperar datos de MongoDB desde Scala

Hemos sido capaces de recuperar datos que están en la raiz de la colección, dentro de un objeto y de un array.

Pero ahora se complica la cosa porque tenemos que recuperar campos que están en un objeto, que está en un array, y éste está dentro de otro objeto

Por si se ve más claro (queremos extraer con Scala el código marcado en amarillo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente se recoge la información con un proceso de PENTAHO con el siguiente código:

```
db.ProductContent.aggregate(
    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
               "Info.CitiesOrder.Code" : 1,
               "Info.CitiesOrder.Type" : 1,
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
            "path":"$Info.CitiesOrder"
            }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
            $sort: {
              _id: 1,
                   "Info.CitiesOrder.Code": 1,
                   "Info.CitiesOrder.Type":1
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: Realmente no se ve más claro: pon siempre el código, la salida y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Gracias y disculpad, ahora mismo consigo el código y lo pongo!

Comment: Por otro lado, supongo que el tema principal es el procesado del fichero json y que no influye el que haya sido extraído de mongodb. Si puedes, especifica los módulo scala que usas, si está usando directamente scala.js (javascript) o usas algún framework para scala/jvm como play o spray. Cuanta más información, mejor te podremos responder.

Answer (score 0):

con:

```
getBsonToStringList(response.get("Info").get.asInstanceOf[BsonDocument].get("Tags").asInstanceOf[BsonArray])
```

somos capaces de recoger los datos del array Tags que está en el objeto Info
pero no somos capaces de recuperar datos del array que son objetos
El objeto getBsonToStringList está definido con:

```
private def getBsonToStringList(doc: BsonArray): List[String] = {
    val it = doc.listIterator()
    var value: List[String] = List()
    while (it.hasNext) {
      value = value :+ it.next().asInstanceOf[BsonString].getValue
    }
    value
  }
```

por ejemplo, dentro del campo objeto "Info" está el campo array CitiesOrder, cuyos campos son objetos con un campo llamado Type
Cómo recogería los valores de Type?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esta es la sección de _respuestas_. Si tienes otra pregunta, debes formularla como tal. Puedes hacer referencia a esta pregunta si proporciona más contexto. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.